# SSH in to GCE instance fail despite the right SSH configuration

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to SSH in to GCE instance with gcompute ssh. I seem to have done everything right so far but when I run

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone "us-central1-b" --project "projectname" "instancename" --ssh-flag="-v"
```

I get

> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>
> debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
>
> debug1: Connecting to 104.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22.
>
> debug1: Connection established.
>
> debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/google_compute_engine type 0
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/google_compute_engine-cert type -1
>
> debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
>
> debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
>
> debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
>
> debug1: Authenticating to 104.XXX.XXX.XXX:22 as 'myusername'
>
> debug1: using hostkeyalias: compute.1694426511137997XXXX
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>
> debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
>
> debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
>
> debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com 
>   compression: none
>
> debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
>
> debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
>
> debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
>
> debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa 
>   SHA256:CYfI+cpP+T4kyOTSjoe80CUgt0GL3tXisLch/8axxx
>
> debug1: using hostkeyalias: compute.1694426511137997XXXX
>   debug1: Host 'compute.1694426511137997XXXX' is known and matches the RSA host key.
>
> debug1: Found key in /Users/myusername/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts:1
>
> debug1: rekey after 429496XXXX blocks
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>
> debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>
> debug1: Offering public key: RSA 
>   SHA256:rP2W5aPDGoUEqYu0XYUaTuqUZ7/FqRTTuc3HOWaXxxx /Users/myusername/.ssh/google_compute_engine
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>
> debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
>   myusername@104.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

Here's what I have tried so far

1. Deleted my SSH keys from project metadata page
2. Compute instances are setup to inherit the SSH keys from project, so there was nothing to change in the SSH page of the instances
3. I authenticated with Gcloud again with ‘gcloud auth login’ using my account.
4. I then did the ‘gcloud init’ to again setup the configuration, default project and timezone
5. Verified that firewall on port 22 is open using ‘gcloud compute firewall-rules list’
6. Renewed my rsa public key using ‘ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine -C myusername’
7. Updated the gcloud metadata with new public key using ‘gcloud compute ssh svuppala@instancename’
8. Verified the same at https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/metadata/sshKeys?project=xxx
9. Reinstalled gcloud sdk and performed the above steps again
10. I never added any keys to the instance directly

I seem to have exhausted all the options here. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you ssh'ing in from your laptop, from cloud shell or from another vm in your gcloud (bastion host)?

Comment: Please check inside of the instance if the public key is successfully  added to authorized_keys. $ find / -name authorized_keys -exec cat {} +

Comment: If one cannot ssh into the instance, how can one manually create authorized_keys? @Alessio

Comment: Problem still persists. I verified authorized_keys file has my public key in it. Im working with a Google rep on this. Will update the thread as soon I resolve the issue.